# Sinon Stub depedent class in node.js module

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon

I have one class as below

```
nx-user.js
class NXUser {
constructor() {}

view(guid, data) {
  //do something
}

}
```

Then I have user controller module as below which has dependency of NxUser class

userController.js

```
const userDb = new NXUser();
import NXUser from "../../../persistence/nx-user";
const allUsers = () => {
    return userDb.view()
}
```

export {allUsers }

I have below code written for stubbing view function of NxUser class for controller unit tests. But its not working. It always calling actual one instated of stubbed one

userController-test.js

```
let userdb=NXUser();
describe("user controller", function () {
 let stubValue = [{
  "name": "Urvashi Parmar",
  "email": "urvashi.parmar@nationalexpress.com"]}

  it("Should create user", () => {           
            sinon.stub(userdb, 'create').resolves(stubValue);            
            userController.allUsers ().then((body) => {
                expect(body[0].name).to.equal(stubValue .name);
                done();
            });
        })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I can not comment yet, so I need to give full answer.

Confusion: at your userController-test.js, you are trying to test NXUser.create, while at file nx-user.js has no definition of create.

Assume: you are trying to test NXUser.view.

This example is created based on your code, and is working fine. Console log "Called" will not get called.

Highlight:

1. Stub NXUser view directly, not userdb.create;
2. I use async-await inside test.

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

class NXUser {
  constructor() {}
  view(guid, data) {
    console.log('Called');
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve([]));
  }
  // Add this only for dummy.
  create() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve([]));
  }
}

const userController = {
  allUsers() {
    const userDb = new NXUser();
    return userDb.view();
  }
}

describe('user controller', function () {
  // Suppose you test view user.
  it('should view user', async function () {
    const stubValue = [{
      name: 'Urvashi Parmar',
      email: 'urvashi.parmar@nationalexpress.com'
    }];
    // Suppose you stub method view and not create.
    const stubUserDBView = sinon.stub(NXUser.prototype, 'view');
    stubUserDBView.resolves(stubValue);

    const body = await userController.allUsers();
    expect(body).to.be.an('array').that.have.lengthOf(1);
    expect(body[0]).to.have.property('name', stubValue[0].name);

    // Restore stub.
    stubUserDBView.restore();
  });
});
```

```
$ npx mocha stackoverflow.js


  user controller
    ✓ should view user


  1 passing (11ms)

$
```

Hope this helps.